# How did the inspector know that the report was fake?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

A man was murdered in a village and the police inspector asked two constables to go to the scene and provide a First Information Report (FIR)...
As it was night and the location was too far from the station, the constables did not go and made a fake FIR. After reading the report, the inspector said "you are both suspended for making a fake report".

**Here is the FIR report:**

"When we arrived at the scene, the door was open and a man aged about 40-45 was found dead in a chair. A bulb was glowing in the room and the fan was switched on. There was a table in front of the dead body and the table contained an opened bottle of poison, a half-filled drinking water bottle, a pen, a newspaper that was opened to pages 9-10, one table top calendar opened at June 20, a 5 rupee coin, and one notebook.  One bed was also in the room.

It seems that this person committed suicide."

> The question is: How did the inspector know that the report was fake and that the constables did not go to the location of the incident?

Comment: Down voters would like to comment?

Comment: I found the puzzle too artificial, like the crucial detail was shoehorned in for the sake of a puzzle without making sense in the context of the story.

Comment: @xnor, oh common its purely logical and  whatever it is artificial, SO doesn't says we should not ask artificial puzzles.

Comment: Don't tell downvoters to comment and then attack their criticism. Protip, if someone takes the time to give you constructive feedback, thank them, and then choose yourself whether to follow it.

Comment: @Lopsy  if downvoters doesn't comment, then how would I know what's the issue and what should be improved, more if they don't have time to provide their feedback then they should not waste their time in clicking downvote.

Comment: @MokshShah Lopsy was referring to your rude response to xnor

Comment: If it was a bottle of poison it would have been a suicide not a murder, unless the man was blind. in which case he wouldn't have the light on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think answer is

> pages 9-10 can not be open at same moment

that's the clue that report was fake

Answer (score 7):

Man was Murdered,  but,  FIR says  suicide.   Hence, inspector  feel fake FIR

Comment: To the downvoter: this answer has correctly identified a loophole in the question: "A man was murdered" is the opening sentence, but the FIR says "It seems that this person committed suicide."

Comment: @randal'thor but presumably neither the inspector nor the constables can have read the opening sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The report read:

> "A bulb was glowing in the room and the fan was switched on."

Now consider the first line of the question:-

> A man was murdered in a village.

The Police Inspector read the report:-

> ...A bulb was glowing in the room and the fan was switched on.

suspected if there could be electricity at night in a village (especially in India), so he found that the report was fake.

Anyways, @user2408578's is the best but this could be a possible explaination.

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer is:

> News paper shows even and odd numbers when opened. In the story it says 9-10 which is incorrect.

Hence fake FIR

Comment: I believe this answer has already been posted before.